# CSS even/odd rows & nested table

Tags: html, css

I have a table generated with JavaScript. Each row in the table can have drop-down-like AJAX-based action, that inserts a row with nested table containing records child elements. Obviously AJAX is performed only once and the rest of expand/collapse actions are CSS show/hide animations.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>action</th>
            <th>property A</th>
            <th>property B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- not yet requested -->
        <tr>
            <td>show</td>
            <td>some value</td>
            <td>some other value</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- expanded -->
        <tr>
            <td>hide</td>
            <td>some value</td>
            <td>some other value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <table>...</table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- collapsed -->
        <tr>
            <td>show</td>
            <td>some value</td>
            <td>some other value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:none;">
            <td colspan="3">
                <table>...</table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem I've got is tables color consitency:
1.) I use tr:nth-child(odd) and tr:nth-child(even) selectors. If nested table is hidden, there are two rows with same color (what a surprise!).
2.) Rows have also .hover selector, so when hovering over nested table, bad things happen (EDIT: this means that if row has .hover background-color:red, hover over nested tables rows will cause nested table to be red, because it is contained in that row)

I know it can be solved programaticly via JavaScript, but I would like to avoid this solution. Is there any other way, how to achieve consistent-looking table without programaticly adding odd, even and hover selectors?

Comment: If one row is hidden, it is not taken out of the DOM so CSS will still take it into account when deciding even or odd orders. For problems with the `.hover` class, you will need to elabourate further. There is not enough information based on a very nebulous "*bad things happen*" description.

Comment: Terry, I know that, that's why I am asking if there is another solution. 

Bad things happen explained ;)

Comment: Not sure what you want to use this for, but in my 2 years of web development I've found that for any given problem there's likely a better alternative than using tables.

Comment: Well, tabular data - that's I want to use it for. Data model of both parent and child records is the same. My only problem is "color inconsistency".